# Share one store between vue and electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuex, store

I would like to store some data from within electron's `main.js` so that it can be reactively displayed by a window running vue. I have declared a store within `store/index.js` including state and mutations. This does work when accessed from electron as well as vue but does not share the data between those contexts. So basically vue does not get the data commited within electron.

**How do I commit to a store from my main electron environment and have the change be reactively displayed in my vue window?**

store/index.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {value: ''},
    mutations: {
        set: (state, payload) => {
            state.value = payload;
        }
    }
});
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ $store.state.value }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from "./store";

export default {
  data: () => ({
  }),
  created() {
    // Commiting here displays the value
    store.commit("set", 'dummy1');
  }
}
</script>
```

background.js

```js
'use strict'
import store from "./store";
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION
    }
  })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  createWindow()
  // Commiting here does not display the changes
  store.commit("set", 'dummy2');
})

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', (data) => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}
```

I suspect that this does actually create two seperate stores that do not share their contents

Answer (score 0):

> this does actually create two separate
> Exactly. In 2 different processes.

But here is 2 possible approaches to start with:

- Use IPC to [communicate between Renderer and Background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254992/533976)
- Try this package [vuex-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-electron) (it also uses IPC under the hood)