# How to create BrowserWindow with data, and get that data in vue app?

Tags: vue.js, electron

I have a `Electron-Vue` project, and in this project i want to pass data to window when I want to show or create it, then get that data and pass to `VUE` application, to specify state for application.

And the data which i want to pass is a string to specify application state something like :

`download` or `main` or `etc`

then with above strings I'll set state in my application to render layouts base on specific state on creating window. basically i want to pass `main for win` and `download for downloadWin`

Here's `background.js` which i want to pass my data in `new BrowserWindow()`, i don't want to use `ipcRendeder or ipcMain`.

```
let win
let downloadWin
function createDownloadWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  downloadWin = new BrowserWindow({ // if it's win i wanna pass main if it's downloadWin i wanna pass download
    title: 'Manage Downloads',
    width: 1200,
    height: 700,
    minWidth: 1200,
    minHeight: 700,
    frame: false,
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
      devTools: true,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"), /* eng-disable PRELOAD_JS_CHECK */
    }
  })
}
```

Now i want to get above string from creating window in `main.js` to pass received data from `mainProcess` to `vue` app.

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,    
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('window/setWindowStat', '//SET STRING HERE')
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any data you want via IPC:

- in the Main process: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main
- in the Renderer process: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer

Here is an example:

```
// In main process.
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')

ipcMain.on('hey', (event, arg) => {
  console.log('hey from win', arg) // prints "{a: 2}" in main process console
})

// send message to your window when it ready (win is your window)
win.webContents.send('hi', {data: 'is here'})
```

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

ipcRenderer.on('hi', (e, payload) => {
  console.log('hi from main', payload) // prints: {data: 'is here'} in dev tools
})
    
ipcRenderer.send('hey', 'ping', {a: 2})
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer, I already know about `ipcMain and ipcRenderer` as i said in question detail i don't want to use them. I'm using Vue and when i open new browser with same structure, conflicts happen when i try to use events emitter.